# Relation between number of edges and vertices in a DAG

Tags: graphs

I conjecture that, in a Directed Acyclic Graph, $O(|V|) = O(|E|)$. Is this statement correct, can it be refined? This is probably standard material; is there a simple reference about this?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29#Transitivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum number of edges in a DAG with n vertices is $\Theta(n^2)$.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699095/how-many-edges-can-there-be-in-a-dag

Answer (score 4):

Take the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ and direct all edges from left to right. This is a DAG with $2n$ vertices and $n^2$ edges.

Comment: n(n-1)/2 edges, more precisely.

Comment: It seems to me this would only show a lower bound, not an upper bound, for the number of edges for any DAG with $|V|$ nodes.